# adding days to date (date coming from data base ), not getting the right anwer

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, php-5.3

i am using the following code 
      `$date =date('Y/m/d',2011-07-06);
       $newdate = strtotime ( '+1 day' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
       $newdate = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $newdate );
       echo $newdate;`

Answer should be **2011-07-08** but the answer is **1970-01-02** 
i am using php 5.3.5 
i am using phpmyadmin

thanks in advance for your help faizi

Answer (score 4):

```
$date = date('Y/m/d',2011-07-06);
```

... won't work. date() requires the 2nd param be a timestamp. Just do this instead ...

```
$newdate = strtotime ( '+1 day' , strtotime ( '2011-07-06' ) ) ;
```

Comment: but my value is coming from database , so its showing 1970-01-02 still

Answer (score 0):

```
$date =date('Y/m/d', strtotime('6 July 2011'));
$newdate = strtotime ( '+1 day' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
$newdate = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $newdate );
echo $newdate;
```